# How to use composer with php 7.2 with docker compose

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, docker-compose

I'm trying to create a simple dev env for a web symfony app with docker compose. My problem is when trying to execute composer install I get this error:

```
- doctrine/collections v1.5.0 requires php ^7.1 -> your PHP version (7.0.7) does not satisfy that requirement.
```

Here's the Composer part of my docker compose file:

```
composer:
        restart: 'no'
        image: composer/composer:php7
        command: install
        volumes:
           - .:/app
```

So that install a php 7.0 and I need at least 7.1. I tried with composer/composer:php7.1 but didn't work.

Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use just `image: "composer"` instead, that's not the official image.

Comment: I get `docker.io/composer/composer:php7: not found`

Answer (score 11):

[`composer/composer`](https://hub.docker.com/r/composer/composer/) image has been deprecated and moved to the official composer [Docker Container](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/composer/). So you can replace:

```
image: composer/composer:php7
```

with:

```
image: "composer"
```

Take the time to check the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/composer/docker/blob/4b4c610a981fd8f41756648de4ba15d84e486282/1.6/Dockerfile) so you can see that `php:7-alpine` is used and then if you check its [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/f4baf0edbc4e05e241938c68bcc7c9635707583d/7.2/alpine3.7/cli/Dockerfile) you'll see `PHP_VERSION 7.2.1`.

Answer (score 1):

you can create your custom DOCKERFILE and build an image with php7.1

Comment: this may solve your problem: https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-create-docker-images-with-dockerfile/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--ignore-platform-reqs` option

This option will ignore php, hhvm, lib-* and ext-* requirements and force the installation even if the local machine does not fulfill these.

Please refer to doc https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md

Comment: docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
it works! Thank you!